# Order of polygons coordinates in android google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, coordinates, polygon

I am new in android. I have some issue with google map polygon. The task is to draw a polygon using 4 points. I receive current and previous coordinates  from outside gps module and compute 2 offsets coordinates for each point  using SphericalUtil.I need to build a polygon through 4 offset coordinates. For example i receive first, second, third, fourth. If i add these coordinates into google map in this order it shows correct.

Correct:

[image: Correct result]

But if order changes, for example first, fourth, second,  third, it draws like hourglass and there isn't any filling. Is there any way to draw a correct polygon independent of LatLang order?

Wrong:

[image: Wrong result]